# OpenCV Mat object copying speed up

Tags: c++, opencv, video-processing

Recently i switched from opencv-python to c++ version of opencv, because i want to speed up my real time video-processing app with CUDA. I am new to C++ so i found some unclear moments with memory management while optimizing my code.

For example, i have some filter chain like this:

```
void apply_blue_edgess(cv::Mat& matrix, cv::Mat& mask, cv::Mat& inverted_mask) {

      cv::Mat gray_image, blured, canny, canny_3d, in_range_mask;

      cv::cvtColor( matrix, gray_image, CV_BGR2GRAY );
      cv::GaussianBlur( gray_image, blured, cv::Size( 5, 5 ), 0, 0 );
      cv::Canny(blured, canny, 0, 100);
      cv::cvtColor( canny, canny_3d, CV_GRAY2BGR );
      cv::inRange(canny_3d, cv::Scalar(255,255,255), cv::Scalar(255,255,255), in_range_mask);
      canny_3d.setTo(cv::Scalar(0, 171, 255), in_range_mask);
      cv::GaussianBlur( canny_3d, matrix, cv::Size( 5, 5 ), 0, 0 );
      cv::bitwise_and(matrix, mask, matrix);
}
```

**Is it ok to use new Mat object at every step of the filter chain** (`gray_image, blured, canny, canny_3d, in_range_mask`) ? Is such continuous memory allocation bad for performance? If so, how should i write similar functions?

---

**As was suggested in the comment section, i ended up doing functor wrapper:**

```
struct blue_edges_filter {
  blue_edges_filter(int width, int height)
  : gray_image(width, height, CV_8UC1),
    blured(width, height, CV_8UC1),
    canny(width, height, CV_8UC1),
    canny_3d(width, height, CV_8UC3),
    in_range_mask(width, height, CV_8UC3)
  {  }

  int operator()(cv::Mat& matrix, cv::Mat& mask, cv::Mat& inverted_mask) {

    cv::bitwise_and(matrix, mask, internal_mask_matrix);
    cv::bitwise_and(matrix, inverted_mask, external_mask_matrix);

    cv::cvtColor( matrix, gray_image, CV_BGR2GRAY );
    cv::GaussianBlur( gray_image, blured, cv::Size( 5, 5 ), 0, 0 );
    cv::Canny(blured, canny, 0, 100);
    cv::cvtColor( canny, canny_3d, CV_GRAY2BGR );
    cv::inRange(canny_3d, cv::Scalar(255,255,255), cv::Scalar(255,255,255), in_range_mask);
    canny_3d.setTo(cv::Scalar(0, 171, 255), in_range_mask);
    cv::GaussianBlur( canny_3d, matrix, cv::Size( 5, 5 ), 0, 0 );
    cv::bitwise_and(matrix, mask, matrix);

  }

  private:
    cv::Mat gray_image, blured, canny, canny_3d, in_range_mask;
};

//Usage
blue_edges_filter apply_blue_edgess(1024, 576);
apply_blue_edgess(matrix, mask, inverted_mask);
```

Comment: in c++ this will allocate memory more than necessary, but I don't think it will be the bottleneck.

Comment: @appleapple From personal experience, the overhead can be quite noticeable. As usual, best to make some actual measurements. Assuming this is called repeatedly with same-size images, it would probably be useful to reuse the temporary variables in subsequent function calls (e.g. turn it into a functor and make those `Mat` member variables.)

Comment: @DanMašek good point about repeated call to this function :)

Comment: @DanMašek, Thanks! I have not heard about functor concept before

Comment: @luddite478 a simple change with similar effect is use static local variable, but I'd not recommend it for `gpumat` which would probably cause trouble.

Answer (score -3):

You can reuse memory without allocation. Create temporal images:

```
  void apply_blue_edgess(cv::Mat& matrix, cv::Mat& mask, cv::Mat& inverted_mask)
  {
        cv::Mat tmp[2];
        int srcInd = 1;
        auto InvInd = [&]() -> int { return srcInd ? 0 : 1; };
        cv::cvtColor( matrix, tmp[InvInd()], CV_BGR2GRAY );
        srcInd = InvInd();
        cv::GaussianBlur( tmp[srcInd], tmp[InvInd()], cv::Size( 5, 5 ), 0, 0 );
        srcInd = InvInd();
        cv::Canny(tmp[srcInd], tmp[InvInd()], 0, 100);
        srcInd = InvInd();
        cv::cvtColor( tmp[srcInd], tmp[InvInd()], CV_GRAY2BGR );
        srcInd = InvInd();
        cv::inRange(tmp[srcInd], cv::Scalar(255,255,255), cv::Scalar(255,255,255), tmp[InvInd()]);
        tmp[srcInd].setTo(cv::Scalar(0, 171, 255), tmp[InvInd()]);
        cv::GaussianBlur( tmp[srcInd], matrix, cv::Size( 5, 5 ), 0, 0 );
        cv::bitwise_and(matrix, mask, matrix);
  }
```